# Error in svd(x, nu = 12, nv = 12) : infinite or missing values in 'x'

Tags: r, svd

I have a dataframe named "train2" 
columns: Store, Dept, Date, Weekly_Sales, IsHoliday
colclasses: factor, factor, Date, numeric, logical

when i try to do singular value decomposition like this:

```
n.comp = 12
train2[is.na(train2)] <- 0
z <- svd(train2[, 2:ncol(train2)], nu=n.comp, nv=n.comp)
```

it throws me error: 
Error in svd(train2[, 2:ncol(train2)], nu = n.comp, nv = n.comp) : 
  infinite or missing values in 'x'

there are no missing values or rows with 0.
What could be the issue?

Date format is "2016-01-12"

help please

Comment: Are values `Inf` or `-Inf` in `train2`? ( `is.na(Inf)` gives `FALSE`) Eventually you need also `train2[is.infinite(train2)] <- 0`

Comment: **Correction** `train2[is.infinite(train2)] <- 0` doesnt work since is.infinite does not work with data frames. It works with list. I have checked with a function: `is.infinite.data.frame <- function(obj){
  sapply(obj,FUN = function(x) all(is.infinite(x)))
}
train2[is.infinite.data.frame(train2)]`  result is data frame with 0 columns where it is infinite

Comment: When i try svd() for individually to [,3] or [,4] or [,5] it's fine. But when it is [,2] then it throws same error.  when I try [,3:5] again error.